# Java. IO. Как преобразуются типы?

Tags: java, io

```
String check = "word";
void dropAbuses(InputStream src, OutputStream dst) throws IOException {
    while (true) {
        int element = src.read();
        if (element != -1) {
            dst.write(element);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

У меня вот такой код, но я не могу понять несколько моментов которые сводятся к одному:

1. Если метод `.write(byte[])` в качестве аргумента требует массив байтов (что вполне логично и среда разработки это подсвечивает), то каким образом он соглашается с тем что я посылаю ему `int`?
2. как мне `int` полученный из `src.read()` снова превратить в массив байтов?

Просто почему я спрашиваю? мне надо перед тем как я сделаю операцию `dst.write(element)` проверить что "word" туда не входит а если входит то не копировать а пропустить.

То есть сейчас метод просто копирует а мне нужен метод-фильтр и вопрос заключается в том как мне эту фильтрацию реализовать? Первое что приходит это `"word"` развалить на байты `byte[] bytes = "word".getBytes()` и сравнивать с результатом `src.read()` а он int возвращает зараза! И что делать???

Конечно можно попробовать "word" представить как `int`. Но все-таки неужели я не могу результат чтения из `InputStream`, интерфейс предназначенный для работы с потоками байтов, представить как массив байтов? Помогите разобраться что я не так понял?

```
void dropAbuses(InputStream src, OutputStream dst, String[] words) {
        try (Close close = new Close()) {
            int[] forCheck = new int[words.length];
            for (int i = 0; i != words.length; i++) {
                forCheck[i] = new ByteArrayInputStream(words[i].getBytes("UTF8")).read();
            }

            while (true) {
                boolean equal = true;
                int element = src.read();
                if (element != -1) {
                    int i;
                    for (i = 0; i != words.length; i++) {
                        if (forCheck[i] == element) {
                            equal = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (equal) dst.write(element);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Да вот пришлось так делать((( но все равно он не словами а отдельными буквами удаляет. А с словами не получается. Да и к стати только английский алфавит рендерит может кто знает в чем нюанс?

Comment: `InputStream` и `OutputStream` -- абстрактные классы. В `OutputStream` есть абстрактный метод `write (int b)`. Вы же Ваш метод используете с какими-то не абстрактными классами, отсюда и получаете реализацию `write (int b)` у сабкласса `OutputStream`. Чтобы получить массив байтов, можно воспользоваться методом `int read(byte[] b)` у `InputStream`.

Comment: >>>>Чтобы получить массив байтов, можно воспользоваться методом int read(byte[] b).<<<< Как получить массив байтов если он принимаем массив байтов а возвращает int?

Comment: @Павел возращает он количество реально прочитанных байт. Дело в том, что массив может быть больше количества байт к прочтению, тогда он заполнится не полностью.

Comment: @Павел, Вы передаете в метод `read(...)` буфер – `byte[] b`, вот именно там и окажутся считанные данные.

Comment: @Павел вчера очень торопился, поэтому невнимательно прочел вашу задачу. Свой ответ ниже дополнил решением.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InputStream` - Абстрактный класс для чтения байт. Его метод `read` перегружен. Если использовать его без аргументов, то он вернет байт, расширенный до `int`. Если передать в него массив байт, то вернет он количество реальной прочитанных байт.

`OutputStream` - Абстрактный класс для записи байт. Его метод `write` перегружен и может принимать массив `byte` или один `byte`, который автоматически расширяется до int. Ничего не возвращает.

Поробнее о них можно почитать [здесь](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) и [здесь](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html).

[Вот](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-MwbLywpV9U&index=6&list=PLlb7e2G7aSpRSBWi5jbGjIe-v_CjRO_Ug) хорошая видео лекция по этой теме на русском.

По поводу Вашей задачи... Что мешает Вам считать поток байт, потом сделать из них строку (`new String(bytes[]`) ? Далее Вы можете вызвать метод `replaceAll`. Например, такой метод вернет вам строку без `word`: `mystring.replaceAll("word", "")`. Далее вы вызываете у полученной строки метод `getBytes` и можете делать c полученными байтами все, что хотите. Например, записать в поток вывода.

Продемонстрирую свою идею на примере. У меня есть файл `fil1.txt` с таким содержимым:

```
This word has to be deleted!
```

Прогоняю его через такой тестовый класс:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/home/someone/file1.txt");
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("/home/someone/file2.txt");

        dropAbuses(fileInputStream, fileOutputStream);

        fileInputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
    }

    static void dropAbuses(InputStream src, OutputStream dst) throws IOException {

        byte bytes[] = new byte[src.available()];
        src.read(bytes);
        String stringWithoutWord = new String(bytes).replaceAll("word ", "");

        dst.write(stringWithoutWord.getBytes());
        dst.flush();
    }

}
```

Содержимое `file2.txt`:

```
This has to be deleted!
```

Слово `word` пропало. Что и требовалось. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Если метод `.write(byte[])` в качестве аргумента требует массив байтов (что вполне логично и среда разработки это подсвечивает), то каким образом он соглашается с тем что я посылаю ему `int`?

`OutputStream` – абстрактный класс, метод `write(...)` которого имеет три сигнатуры:

1. `void write(byte[] b)`;
2. `void write(byte[] b, int off, int len)`;
3. `abstract void write(int b)`.

В Ваш метод:

```
void dropAbuses(InputStream src, OutputStream dst, String[] words)
```

в качестве `dst` Вы передаете какой-либо **не абстрактный** сабкласс класса `OutputStream`, в котором реализован метод `void write(int b)`, собственно поэтому Вы и можете передавать в метод `write(...)` параметр типа `int`.

Например, если Вы передадите в Ваш метод в качестве `dst` объект класса `DataOutputStream`, то при вызове `dst.write(5)` будет вызван метод `void write(int b)` класса `DataOutputStream`.

> как мне `int` полученный из `src.read()` снова превратить в массив байтов.

В массив байтов? Зачем? Метод `read()` класса `InputStream` читает **один** байт и возвращает его `int`-овое представление.

Чтобы из `InputStream` получить массив байтов, можно воспользоваться одним из методов:

1. `int read(byte[] b)`;
2. `int read(byte[] b, int off, int len)`;

При использовании этих методов, считанные байты будут записаны в `byte[] b`, а вернут эти методы **количество** считанных байт.

Comment: >>>В массив байтов? Зачем? Метод read() класса InputStream читает один байт и возвращает его int-овое представление.<<< А если символ не помещается а один байт, UTF8 кодирует кирилицу двумя байтами. И получается при таком подходе все символы больше 1-го бита у меня обрезаются и потом вместо них знаки вопроса...

Comment: @Павел, Для чтения символов целесообразнее использовать `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: Да но как я InputStreamReader приведу к InputStream? Ведь InputStreamReader наследник Reader. А мне надо в метод именно объект InputStream в метод прислать... Это условие моей задачи.

Comment: @Павел, Ну если `мне надо`, то можете поизвращаться с `InputStream`. Я говорил лишь про целесообразность.

Comment: Да я полностью с вами согласен, без всякой иронии... Просто задание такое дали, ничего не поделать. Я думаю как мне теперь это все собирать. Там еще условие что я должен все это делать в потоке не сохраняя никуда... Вообще жесть(((...